How to make the React Native app also display images in the APK file and not just in the emulator
Four days I've been trying to create the android app bundle file but still something doesn't work.
I use yarn in my project. Command yarn start correctly run app on my simulator but when you run react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/ it creates the added folders ‘android\app\src\main\res\drawable-...’. with image files.
The compiler screams that there are duplicates, so I delete them:  rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-* and next i run cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew bundleRelease.
The app builds itself but the apk file does not display the images.
My npx react-native info:
System:
    OS: Windows 11 10.0.22621
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6920HQ CPU @ 2.90GHz
    Memory: 18.22 GB / 31.92 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 20.16.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.22.22 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
    npm: 10.8.2 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 32, 33, 34
      Build Tools: 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 34.0.0
      System Images: android-33 | Google Play Intel x86_64 Atom, android-34 | Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
    Windows SDK:
      AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense: Enabled
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: AI-223.8836.35.2231.11090377
    Visual Studio: Not Found
  Languages:
    Java: 18.0.2.1 - /c/Program Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
    react-native: ^0.71.0 => 0.71.19
    react-native-windows: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found

I use Gradle version: 7.5.1
My android/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")

    }
}

My android/app/build.gradle:
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    namespace 'com.myApp'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
import com.android.build.OutputFile
 
/**
 * This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
 * By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
 */
react {
  
}
 

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
 

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
 

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
 

def reactNativeArchitectures() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
 
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
 
    // namespace "com.myApp"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
 
    splits {}
}
 
dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
 
    implementation("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0")
 
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
 
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle")

Need your help!
I tried everything, I cleaned the cache
rm -rf node_modules **/node_modules && rm -rf yarn.lock **/yarn.lock && yarn cache clean && yarn install, I rummaged through node_modules.
